# Call graphql api from Spring webclient and publish request parameter to the graphql endpoint

Tags: spring-boot, graphql, webclient

I need some help, I am trying to  call graphql api from a rest endpoint using spring webclient . My rest endpoint has some input parameter like authentication token and others parameter.whenever I called the graphql endpont all the i/p should have published to graphql API . I don't have any idea how to do that. As I need to published those request parameter to the graphql api I think from my microservice I need to have a graphql mutation. But how can I published that to the calling API that I don't know. Please provide any reference.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to call a GraphQL API of an external service as a consequence of your REST API being called? Is that it?

Comment: yes, I can call my RestAPI which will be calling internally another graphql api and publishing the restEndpoint request param to graphQL API.

Comment: Are you getting or posting data to the GraphQL API?

Comment: Posting data to graphql through rest endpoint.

Comment: But are you getting data or sending data to the GraphQL API? The first is a query, the second is a mutation. That is why it is important to know what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: Sending data to graphql api and in that case I need to use mutation.